# Don't receive FCM notifications when a fragment is open

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a chat application and I successfully implemented fcm notifications whenever a new message comes in. But my problem is when I am chatting i don't want to receive fcm notifications, since i am in the chat window (My chat fragment) anyway.How can this be implemented?

Comment: maintain a flat in preferences. and disable it before building any notification.

Comment: Is there any other screen where you do want to receive messages having the app in foreground?

Comment: yes i want the notification in every screen except the chat fragment

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting approach with Ordered Broadcasts by Commonsware.

1. Define an action string you will use when the event occurs that you
   want to go to the activity or notification (e.g.,
   `com.commonsware.java.packages.are.fun.EVENT`).
2. Dynamically register a `BroadcastReceiever` in your activity, with an
   `IntentFilter` set up for the aforementioned action string and with a
   positive priority (the default priority for a filter is 0). This
   receiver should then have the activity do whatever it needs to do to
   update the UI based on this event. The receiver should also call
   `abortBroadcast()` to prevent others from getting it. Be sure to
   register the receiver in `onStart()` or `onResume()` and unregister the
   receiver in the corresponding `onStop` or `onPause()` method.
3. Register in your manifest a `BroadcastReceiver`, with an
   `<intent-filter>` set up for the aforementioned action string. This
   receiver should raise the Notification.
4. In your service (e.g., an `IntentService`), when the event occurs,
   call `sendOrderedBroadcast()`.

Full description [here.](https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html)

Comment: I think FCM makes it easier. When the app is in forreground you count with a handler with onMessageReceived() where you can decide what do with it.

Comment: @Juan that work for foreground/background status for the whole app. This works per activity/fragment